# Defining a custom newcommand-like command

Tags: macros

For a package I'm writing, I would like to provide a customised way to create a new command. The idea is that the user will write something like

```
\DeclareFancyThing{\myfancything}{parameter1}{parameter2}
```

and then this will create a command `\myfancything`, which itself takes an argument or two.

I was pleased and surprised to find that the following MWE does actually work, and produces the words "fancy foo!" as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mynewcommand}[2]{%
    \newcommand{#1}{fancy #2!}%
}

\mynewcommand{\foo}{foo}

\begin{document}
\foo
\end{document}
```

However, I can't work out how to make it so that the generated command `\foo` itself takes an argument. Is there a way to do that?

The following might be expected to produce the words "fancy foo (bar)!", but it in fact gives the error "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000]."

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mynewcommand}[2]{%
    \newcommand{#1}[1]{fancy #2 (#1)!}%
}

\mynewcommand{\foo}{foo}

\begin{document}
\foo{bar}
\end{document}
```

I guess the issue is that the #1 refers to the first argument of `\mynewcommand` instead of the argument of `\foo`, but I don't know how to change that.

**Edit:** The question is rightly closed, so I can't post an answer - but in order to help future visitors, in case the comments get deleted, the following works fine and produces "fancy foo (bar)!".

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mynewcommand}[2]{%
    \newcommand{#1}[1]{fancy #2 (##1)!}%
}

\mynewcommand{\foo}{foo}

\begin{document}
\foo{bar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to double the `#`, i.e., `##1`. For example `\newcommand{\mynewcommand}[2]{
    \newcommand{#1}[1]{fancy #2! ##1!}
}` works. But why would you want to do that when `\newcommand` already exists?

Comment: @Marijn the reason is because I want my users (i.e. me) to be able to write `\DeclareFancyThing{\foo}{1}{7}{14.2}{8}{hello}` and then after that just write `\foo{42}`, instead of having to write `\fancyThing{42}{1}{7}{14.2}{8}{hello}` every time they use the command. Of course the user can write `\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\fancyThing{#1}{1}{7}{14.2}{8}{hello}}` themself, but since every document will contain several such lines I wanted to automate it.

Comment: @Marijn it's not particularly easier, but it looks marginally more logical in the source code. It's all just aesthetics I guess.

Comment: Of course it is your choice which interfaces you provide for users - however you could run into trouble trying to reinvent the wheel for only a small gain, so be careful what you wish for :)

Comment: @Marijn fair enough, point well taken. If you want the points feel free to post your first comment as an answer and I'll accept it - it does answer the question as asked.

Comment: Let me see if I can find a duplicate, it is a common technique for carrying over arguments in nested definitions (there is also `###1`, `####1` etc. for deeper nesting).

Comment: apart from needing `##` you are missing `%` at ends of lines, your definition is creating multiple space tokens each time it is used

Comment: @DavidCarlisle hopefully that's fixed now.

Comment: @Marijn `###1` is nonsense. We have `##1` for first level of nesting, `####1` for second etc. We must to double all `#` in each next level.